# Unable to open a zip file that was made in Python

Tags: python, numpy, zip, conv-neural-network

I have created 1594 .npz files from dicom files after preprocessing. Now I want to open there zip files using np.load() method but its giving the bad zip file error. The thing is, this is working for a batch of 20 but not 1594. Is it because np.load() cant open so many zip files or would there have been a problem while creating the zip files like a disturbance thats causing this error?

```
patients = os.listdir(preprocessed_data_folder)
shuffle(patients) # randomize the order of data
# initialization
for i in range(len(patients)):  
if patients[i].startswith('.'): continue # ignore hidden files
#patient_data = 
if np.load(preprocessed_data_folder + patients[i])['set'] == 'test': continue
```

The error I'm getting is

```
      C:\Users\sahana\anaconda3\lib\zipfile.py in _RealGetContents(self)
      1323             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
      1324         if not endrec:
      -> 1325             raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
      1326         if self.debug > 1:
      1327             print(endrec)

      BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

Comment: The error message `File is not a zip file` suggests you have a bad zip file. Add some debugging to your code to identify the zip file it doesn't like, the run `unzip -t filename`  to see what  `unzip` thinks about the file.

Comment: hello, it took me 4 days to pre-process all the data into 1594 zip files, so is there any way I can check which files are bad zip files?

Comment: Sure, just write a few lines of shell script to run `unzip -t` on all the files and print out the ones that fail the validation.

Comment: But also: are you sure your `processed_data_folder` contains only zip files?

Comment: yes it only contains zip files in the form of .npz . If there any way I can check using python code?

Comment: On the line before you do the `np.load` print the filename. The last filename output before the code crashes will tell you the name of the problem file.

Comment: thank you I printed all patients and found which zip file was corrupt.